# How to Show SQLite table in Logcat

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, android-studio

Database Helper

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// Table Name
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Contacts";

// Table columns
public static final String ID = "ID";
public static final String Contact_Name = "Contact_Name";
public static final String Phone_Number = "Phone_Number";
public static final String Favourites = "Favourites";

// Database Information
static final String DB_NAME = "MessagePlus_Contacts";

// database version
static final int DB_VERSION = 1;

// Creating table query
private static final String CREATE_TABLE = "Create Table " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + ID
        + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " + Contact_Name + " TEXT NOT NULL, " + Phone_Number + " INT NOT NULL, " + Favourites + " Boolean NOT NULL);";

private static final String Show_Table = "Select * From " + TABLE_NAME;

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void showData(SQLiteDatabase db){db.execSQL(Show_Table);}

public void insertData(String contactName, String phoneNumber,String favourites) {

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(DatabaseHelper.Contact_Name, contactName);
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.Phone_Number, phoneNumber);
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.Favourites, favourites);

    db.insert(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    // close db connection
    db.close();
}

public int addToFavourites(String favourites) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(DatabaseHelper.Favourites, favourites);

    // updating row
    return db.update(DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME, values, DatabaseHelper.Phone_Number + " = ?", new String[]{favourites});
}



public int getCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + DatabaseHelper.TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);

    int count = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();

    // return count
    return count;
}
```

Modal

```
public class FavouritesHelper {
public String Name;
public String PhoneNumber;
public boolean Favourites;

public FavouritesHelper() {
}

public FavouritesHelper(String Name, String PhoneNumber, Boolean Favourites) {
    this.Name = Name;
    this.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
    this.Favourites = Favourites;
}
public String getName() {
    return Name;
}

public void setName(String Name) {
    this.Name = Name;
}

public String getPhoneNumber() {
    return PhoneNumber;
}

public void setPhoneNumber(String PhoneNumber) {
    this.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
}

public boolean getFavourites() {
    return Favourites;
}

public void setFavourites(boolean Favourites) {
    this.Favourites = Favourites;
}
```

}

This is my database helper and I'm trying to fetch the table in logcat but I don't know how to do that. I know the code is `Select * from <tablename>` but how do i implement that. I want to see all the data in my table.

Comment: Yeah... Not just the table column names... the whole data

Comment: I dont know how to do that... cant i just display it in logcat because that is simpler

Comment: Just suggest whatever is best and provide the code please @AshwiniViolet

Comment: Can u answer please @pskink

Comment: Hey @MichelleKinsten I seee you've added a `favorite` Can I see your model class please?

Comment: i dont have a modal class... just iploading directly.... Im just asking how do i show the table thats all @UmangBurman

Comment: @MichelleKinsten Check out the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Soltion:**

Please follow the following steps:

**First Step:**

Make the below method in `DatabaseHelper` class:

```
public List<FavouritesHelper> getAllData() {
    List<FavouritesHelper> data = new ArrayList<>();

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + FavouritesHelper.TABLE_NAME;

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    // looping through all rows and adding to list
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            FavouritesHelper alldata = new FavouritesHelper();

            alldata.setName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FavouritesHelper.Name)));
            alldata.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(FavouritesHelper.PhoneNumber)));
            alldata.setFavourites(cursor.getBoolean(cursor.getColumnIndex(FavouritesHelper.Favourites)));

            data.add(alldata);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }

    // close db connection
    db.close();

    // return notes list
    return data;
}
```

**Second Step:**

In your activity:

declare a global object: `List<FavouritesHelper> AllData` inside your class.

**Third Step:**

then, add this `AllData = new List<FavouritesHelper>();` in your `onCreate()`

**Fourth Step:**

write this in your activity after inserting data: `AllData = database.getAllData();`

**Fifth Step:**

Print it in log using below statement:

```
for(FavouritesHelper helper : AllData) {
     Log.e("values : ", helper.getName() + ", " + helper.getPhoneNumber() + ", " + helper.getFavourites());
}
```

That's it.

Try it out. Hope it Helps.

Comment: What is ContactsHelper ??? That is a modal of a different list and not of the sqlite... i havnt prepared a modal for this table

Comment: @MichelleKinsten Can you post the model of whichever data you want to display on logcat?

Comment: @MichelleKinsten Updated answer.

Comment: its showing
not static field name cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Okay, make the method static in Database Helper class.

Comment: non static field name cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180619/discussion-between-umang-burman-and-michelle-kinsten).

Comment: i tried... what do i search in logcat? because theres no mention of it

Answer (score 1):

As **@pskink** suggested you can use dumpCursor like this

create this method inside your DatabaseHelper class

```
 public  void dumpCursorInLogCat() {

    //here first getting the readable database

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(Show_Table, null);
      //here is how you can Dump cursor
            DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);

            cursor.close();


        }
```

and call this method in your activity whenever you want to show data in logcat

call it inside your activity like

```
new DatabaseHelper(your_activity_name.this).dumpCursorInLogCat();
```

Comment: you don't even need to define this line..just simply  call this method..it will by default put in logcat without Log.d(.....) just call it and you will see@MichelleKinsten

Comment: While calling method it asks to make the method public and static but when i do it wont compile